QuillForms Error Message Not Displaying, how to fix them?
Describe the bug
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/quill-forms-example-typeform-clone-in-react-js-and-typescript-20uuf?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx
I cloned the link above, and when I run it locally, the only issue I'm facing is that the 'field is required' error isn't showing up. However, the same code works perfectly in CodeSandbox.
QuillForms Error message not showing 
i tried it on codesandbox and it is working fine there but not in localhost
